# Вывод рандомного числа в 2 дива, при нажатии на кнопку html

Tags: html, button

```js
function Random() {
  const max = 800;
  return Math.round(Math.random() * max);
}

const btn = document.getElementById('button');
const div = document.getElementById('div');

btn.onclick = function() {
  div.innerHTML = Random();
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Число" id="button">
<div id="div"></div>
```

Есть такой код, как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии 1 кнопки выводилось 2 разные рандомные числа в разных местах?

Answer (score 3):

Что тебе мешает создать новую функцию?

```js
function Random() {
  const max = 800;
  return Math.round(Math.random() * max);
}

function random() {
  const max = 800;
  return Math.round(Math.random() * max);
}

btn.onclick = function() {
  div.innerHTML = Random();
  div1.innerHTML = random();
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Число" id="btn">
<div id="div"></div>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Comment: Зачем ещё одна функция?

Comment: Исходя из примера я добавил еще одну функцию... Я конечно могу еще кучу ( не менее 10ти ) примеров привести, но судя по вопросу, пример был написан не автором вопроса, а откуда то скопирован и это вообще бы запутало автора... Так какой же вариант мне надо было бы выбрать мой милейший друг?

Comment: Вызвать еще раз уже имеющую функцию?

Comment: смотри когда я добавляю ещё одну 1 рандом работает а второй нет тоесть когда я нажимаю на кнопку она только 1 тригерит а надо что бы 2 рандомных числа было